# C++ Different subclasses need different parameters

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance

I'm looking for the best way to accomplish the following:

**Background**

I have a based class with a `request()` virtual method with different subclasses provide alternate implementations of performing the requests.  The idea is I'd like to let the client instantiate one of these subclasses and pass in one of these objects to a subsystem which will call `request()` when it needs to.  The goal is to let the client decide how requests are handled by instantiated the desired subclass.

**Problem**

However, if a certain subclass implementation is chosen, it needs a piece of information from the subsystem which would most naturally be passed as an argument to request (i.e. `request(special_info);`).  But other subclasses don't need this.  Is there a clean way to hide this difference or appropriate design pattern that can be used here?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you feed that information to the handler at construction time?

Answer (score 0):

Make the base `request()` method take the information as argument, and ignore the argument in subclass implementations that don't need it.

Or pass the SubSystem instance itself to the handler, and let the handler get the information it needs from the SubSystem (and ignore it if it doesn't need any information from the SubSystem). That would make the design more extensible: you wouldn't need to pass an additional argument and refactor all the methods each time a new subclass needing additional information is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

JB Nizet's suggestion is one possible solution - it will certainly work.

What worries me a little is the rather vague notion that "some need more information". Where does this information come from, what decides that? The general principle with inheritance is that you have a baseclass that does the right thing for all the objects. If you have to go say "Is it type A object or type B object, then do this, else if it's type C object do something slightly different, and if it's type D object, do a another kind of thing", then you're doing it wrong.

It may be that JB's suggestion is the right one for you, but I would also consider the option that "special_info" can be passed into the constructor, or be fetched via some helper function. The constructor solution is a sane one, because at construction time, obviously, you need to know if something is a A, B, C or D object that you are creating. The helper function is a good solution some other times, but if it's used badly, it can lead to a bit of a messy solution, so use with care.

Generally, when things end up like this, it's because you are splitting the classes up "the wrong way".